# How to draw multiple random obects using canvas in javascript

Tags: javascript, canvas, random

Using canvas I need to create 4 other random shapes to appear in random sizes and random locations. So far I have random circles. But I cant Figure out how to get other shapes as well.

in the body i have

```
<canvas width='600' height='200' id='artCanvas'></canvas>
<form>
  <input type='button' id='artButton' value='New Masterpiece'>
</form>
```

Using this code I need to create multiple other shapes in the same way the circles are being created randomly.

```
<script>
  function makeTitle() {
  //generate the title for your masterpiece
  var lines =[['Meditative','Objective','Reflective'['Ellipses','Tranformation', 'State', 'Emotion', 'Composition']['I', 'II', 'III', 'IV','V']];
  var title = '';
  for (var i=0; i<lines.length; i++) {
    var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * lines[i].length);
    title += lines[i][random] + ' ';
  };
return(title);
}
function artHandler() {
  var title = makeTitle();
  alert(title);
  var canvas = document.getElementById('artCanvas');
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  fillBackgroundColor(canvas, context);
  var colors = ['white', 'yellow', 'blue', 'red'];
  for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    var color = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
    drawCircle(canvas, context, color); 
  }
  drawText(canvas, context, title);
  }
function fillBackgroundColor(canvas, context) {
  var colors = ['white', 'yellow', 'blue', 'red'];
  var bgColor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
  context.fillStyle = bgColor;
  context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}
function degreesToRadians(degrees) {
  return (degrees * Math.PI)/180;
}
// Draws a circle at a random location
function drawCircle(canvas, context, color) {
  var radius = Math.floor(Math.random() * 40);
  var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * canvas.width);
  var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * canvas.height);
  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(x, y, radius, 0, degreesToRadians(360), true);
  context.fillStyle = color;
  context.fill();
}
function drawText(canvas, context, title) {
  context.fillStyle = 'black';
  context.font = 'bold 1em sans-serif';
  context.textAlign = 'right';
  context.fillText(title, canvas.width-20, canvas.height-40);
}
window.onload = function() {
var button = document.getElementById('artButton');
button.onclick = artHandler;
}
</script>
```

Comment: I have put your code in a JSFiddle and it does not work (does not even draw circles for me). There also seems an easily fixable error with a missing `]` in `var lines`'s definition.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/d59gysxb/

Comment: It works, in his code you have to uncomment the last win.onload function in the script

Comment: Please, take the few seconds required to properly indent your code. Nobody wants to read a wall of indented code. Make it easy for us to help you and you'll get much better help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To generate random color, use this function:

```
function getBackgroundColor() {
    return "rgb("+[
        Math.round(Math.random()*0xFF),
        Math.round(Math.random()*0xFF),
        Math.round(Math.random()*0xFF)
    ].join()+")";
}
```

To generate a random rectangle:

```
function drawRect(canvas, context) {
    context.fillStyle = getBackgroundColor();
    context.fillRect(Math.random()*canvas.width, Math.random()*canvas.height,Math.random()*100,Math.random()*100);
}
```

Triangle:

```
function drawTriangle(canvas, context) {
    context.fillStyle = getBackgroundColor();

    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(Math.random()*canvas.width, Math.random()*canvas.height);
    context.lineTo(Math.random()*canvas.width, Math.random()*canvas.height);
    context.lineTo(Math.random()*canvas.width, Math.random()*canvas.height);
    context.fill();

}
```

This is your code, with the random generators:

https://jsfiddle.net/m06e8Lh4/

Comment: It works, in his code you have to uncomment the last win.onload function in the script

Comment: Fixed background color generator, and added alpha

Comment: Now it looks like the opacity is being changed, I dont really need that. And it looks like theyre being stacked on each other when being generated.

Comment: Two comments now, change `rgba` to `rgb`, and `.join(",")` is the exact same as `.join()`.

Comment: Thank you for your remarks. I've edited the code again

Comment: Why create an array and invoke a the join function when with less code and more efficiency you just create the string  r`eturn "rgb("+
        Math.floor(Math.random()*256) +
        Math.floor(Math.random()*256) + 
        Math.floor(Math.random()*256) + ")";`

Comment: Oh and forgot that when you use `Math.round(Math.random() * 255);` you are actually reducing the randomness, as the lowest and highest values will occur half as often then any other number, as the rounding can can never round up to zero or down to the 255. Should be `Math.floor(Math.random() * 256)`

Comment: Is there any way to still make it random, but set a max height and width for the shape, some shapes are too big,  this is what i have now https://jsfiddle.net/d45Lsqxb/

Comment: Also is there anyway to get rid of the random colors and use the colors the way i had it originaly? i cant get the colors back to the way i had it before